# Create junction raster from stream and road rasters

Tags: intersection, overlay, road, rivers, intersect

I have converted two vector polyline datasets to raster format. One represents streams, and one represents roads. I need to create a third raster layer that contains cells where there are stream crossings.

I was going to use a simple boolean AND function to create a raster of stream-road junctions. However, at about 10% of the junctions, the raster lines intersect, but do not overlap. See the figure below.

Is there a tool or established method that edits the road raster to make sure that all road crossings actually have overlap with raster streams dataset?

[image: Road(black) and Stream (blue) intersect but do not overlap]

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: You could look for intersections in the vector layers. See https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.overlay.html or https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.select.html

Comment: I would convert the rasters to polylines and perform the intersection using the vectors.. as you have noticed with the rasters two features can cross without sharing a common pixel. If you *must* do this with rasters then first resample to half the resolution using 'nearest', 'maximum' or 'majority' (how depends on your GIS software) to encourage commonality

Comment: Converting to vectors is the way to go. If this is not an option, expand both by 1 cell and do your raster algebra. Convert output to polygons and compute their centres. Close enough

Comment: @ PolyGeo, I am using Whitebox GAT right now, but I can also use GRASS or Arc. FelixIP, thanks for your comment - it's a good idea.

Comment: @Michael Miles-Stimson and Mankoff, I am modeling culvert locations and need to model them as barriers within the stream, essentially replacing a stream cell with a "culvert" cell. From your advice, I will try to use a vector intersect to identify a cell to represent the culvert.